# Mostrar n cantidad de tablas de DB en archivo de Excel pero en la misma hoja y desplegar todas las tablas hacia la derecha. con C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, excel, libreria

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación de escritorio que se conecta a una base de datos local, y me trae la información en forma de tabla con 4 columnas. Esta tabla la inserto en Excel y la muestro correctamente.

la información me la trae un procedimiento almacenado que al pasarle el id de un registro de la base de datos me trae la información en 4 columnas, cada id es una tabla de base de datos con diferente información.

El problema aquí es que me piden una nueva actualización en la que quieren pasar N cantidad de id al procedimiento y por ende me traiga N cantidad de tablas, PERO todas se muestren en el mismo archivo de Excel y en la misma hoja de Excel, pero cada tabla se despliegue hacia la derecha a través de un espacio, algo así.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento crear un algoritmo que automáticamente despliegue todas las tablas, pero lo que no comprendo mucho es la asignación de las columnas de Excel.

Excel después de la letra z, empieza a crear prefijos con AA, BA, CA, etc. por lo que no entiendo bien como podría hacer que no se equivoque.

adjunto el código que tengo hasta el momento.

```
public void importarExcel(List<Tuple<Int32, String>> lista_exp, string fechaini, string fechafin, int idpo)
    {

        string grupoActual = "";
        string[] letras = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
        int Filatitulo = 1, FilacolumnasDatos = 2, FilasDatos = 3, indiceLetras = 0;
        var lista = lista_exp;

        Excel.Application Mi_Excel = default(Excel.Application);
        Excel.Workbook LibroExcel = default(Excel.Workbook);
        Excel.Worksheet hoja_Excel = default(Excel.Worksheet);

        Mi_Excel = new Excel.Application();
        Mi_Excel.Visible = true;

        LibroExcel = Mi_Excel.Workbooks.Add();
        hoja_Excel = LibroExcel.Worksheets[1];
        hoja_Excel.Visible = Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;

        for (int i = 0; i < lista.Count; i++) {
            string nombre_poliza = lista[i].Item2;
            var resultados = ConexionDB.Instance.DatosExcel(lista[i].Item1, fechaini, fechafin, idpo);
            hoja_Excel.Range[$"A1:A1"].Value = nombre_poliza;

            Excel.Range celda = hoja_Excel.Range["A2", Type.Missing];
            celda.Value = "CUENTA";

            celda = hoja_Excel.Range["B2", Type.Missing];
            celda.Value = "NOMBRE DE LA CUENTA";

            celda = hoja_Excel.Range["C2", Type.Missing];
            celda.Value = "DEBE";

            celda = hoja_Excel.Range["D2", Type.Missing];
            celda.Value = "HABER";

            int index = 3;
            foreach (var r in resultados) {
                hoja_Excel.Cells[index, "A"] = r.Item1;
                hoja_Excel.Cells[index, "B"] = r.Item2;
                hoja_Excel.Cells[index, "C"] = r.Item3;
                hoja_Excel.Cells[index, "D"] = r.Item4;

                index++;
            }



            LibroExcel.PrintPreview();
        }
        MessageBox.Show("creado?");
    }
```

El programa está diseñado en C# con la librería **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** si alguien me diera una idea de cómo lo haría se los agradecería infinitamente.

Comment: Eso no es una base de datos, es un archivo excel

Comment: @LucasBois si, la información la sacamos de una base de datos y la guardamos en un archivo de Excel, esto para hacer graficacion de datos y realizar otro tipo de cálculos hechos por personas que son contadores públicos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo recordar que había una forma de llamar a una columna mediante un número en vez de por letra. Pero no estoy seguro

De todas maneras puedes crear un función, donde le pases el número de columna y retorne la letra. Algo así:

```
 static string[] letras = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

        public static string GetRange(int index)
        {
            if(index<letras.Length) return letras[index];
            return GetRange(index / letras.Length - 1) + letras[(index % letras.Length)];
        }
```

Comment: Hola! es muy buena idea, voy a implementarlo y mostrare mi resultado en un rato.